# Vuejs 3 with CDN and typescript support

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

We are building an application using asp.net core but we also want vuejs3 with typescript. We dont have any SFC or SPA. We just need support for existing razor page hence we dont want CLI. CDN version is working well with JavaScript but I am not able to make it work with typescript. I tried importing the typing files (.d.ts) as standalone from individual node_module folder (compiler/runtime/vue/reactivity etc)

but getting error "cannot find name createapp"

main.ts

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/vue/dist/vue.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.d.ts"/>

const app = createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            product: 'Socksssa',
            image: './assets/images/socks_green.jpg',
            // solution
            url: 'https://www.vuemastery.com/'
            // solution
        }
    }
})

app.mount('#app');
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outFile": "main.js",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [ "*.ts" ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "typings",
    "*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

We dont have any module bundler. I also tried merging all the .d.ts into one file (backtracking from vue.d.ts) but the final output file is 42,000+ records and is still not working. We previously used Vuejs 2 with one single typing file without any issue. Any suggestions or single typescript definition file will be really helpful. I tried searching in DefinitelyTyped and other places but not able to find it.

Our ask is to use vuejs 3 with CDN and typescript.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: From what I am reading in the documentation, it seems that you are going to have to install it using npm or yarn if you want typescript support without any additional tooling. please check: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

Comment: I want vuejs3. For Vuejs2 we already have a typing which is working. For Vuejs3 in documentation I am seeing full CLI only.

Comment: So is it "createapp" or "createApp"? A mistake in error message is misleading. Vue isn't supposed to be used globally with TS. The most straightforward way would be to import it as usual and use Webpack externals https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/ . Otherwise you'll need to define vue global on window on your own

Comment: It is createApp. I typed the error message instead of copy paste. We were able to do Vue with TS in Vue2. We are trying to achieve using webpack or any module bundler.